# How to install git 1.8 or above on Debian Wheezy

Tags: git, debian

I'm trying trying to install a later version of git (primarily 1.8.* or above). if I try and install it using `apt-get install git` I end up installing version `1.7.10.4`.

I have already tried changing the repository using the method below:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install git
```

The output of `apt-get update` just gives the me the following and because of that, I end up installing version `1.7.10.4` again.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I have also tried to install git using a backport, like the following:

```
sudo apt-get install git/wheezy-backports
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install git
```

I never end up getting further than `apt-get install git/wheezy-backports` because then I end up getting the following error:

```
E: Release 'wheezy-backports' for 'git' was not found
```

**How would I install git 1.8.* or above on Debian Wheezy?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would definitely recommend using the backports version. To use the backports repository, keep in mind that you must add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main
```

And then you can retry with apt-get. You will find full instructions at http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2

Comment: I first missed the need to 'apt-get -t squeeze-backports install "package"' - i.e. use the -t flag as indicated behind the link, otherwise apt-get won't find it. Now at git 1.9.1. thx

Comment: added the backports url in source.list ,  as @gheesh said and  fired , commands,   add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install git          works for me perfectly  , checked  git --version , it returned   :   git version 1.7.10.4   , thanks

Answer (score 10):

Let me provide a clean copy/paste solution:

```
echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wheezy-backports.list
sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get -t wheezy-backports install -y -qq git mercurial
```

Comment: fyi, restuled in git 1.9.1 at time of comment. Was good enough for me!

Comment: Thanks, the accepted answer would have worked for me but I forgot to update, which you reminded me of.

Answer (score 0):

Clone it from its repo https://github.com/git/git and compile it yourself. I've done it on Cygwin and it was easy, so it should be OK on Debian. Read the INSTALL file, it is fairly self-explanatory.

If you haven't compiled software before you should know that there will be quite a few pre-requisites required (they are listed in the INSTALL). You should just be able to `apt-get` them.