# Using Git, I have cloned a branch and would like to update to another remote branch

Tags: git, remote-branch

I have cloned a project from Github from branch, say, br1

```
git clone --branch br1 https://www.github.com/project/project /opt/project/
```

I would like to switch to branch br2 as if I had did this from the beginning:

```
git clone --branch br2 https://www.github.com/project/project /opt/project/
```

I don't want all the branches locally, only the one I use since I am on a ressource limited VPS.

Can I do something like this (pseudo code for the first line)?

```
git fetch origin/br2
git branch -D br1
```

EDIT: here is my .config

```
# cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://www.github.com/project/project
[branch "br1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/br1
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository) can help?

Comment: I didnot understand what said, you want to delete branch(br1)?

Comment: @Anjaneyulu Battula: yes, after having fetched branch br2.

Comment: @Zeeker: the explanations in this link remains abstract for me (not git expert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to:

- delete your current repo
- do the clone again

  ```
  git clone --branch br2 https://www.github.com/project/project /opt/project/
  ```

That will limit the network activity to a minimum, like a custom fetch would (but the clone is simpler than the fetch here)

If you want to test the fetch option:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add -t branch2 origin remote-url
git fetch origin
```

Comment: I thought a fetch would save a lot of bandwidth because both branches have a lot in common. The initial cloning took me about 10 minutes.

Comment: @lalebarde true, I have edited the answer, for you to test the fetch first.

Comment: Thanks VonC. When I try `git remote add -t branch2 origin remote-url`, I get `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: @lalebarde try deleting the remote first: `git remote remove origin`

Comment: `error: Unknown subcommand: remove`, but rm works. strange !?

Comment: @lalebarde what git version are you using?

Comment: @lalebarde that explains a lot. Either upgrade, or simply replace br1 with br2 in your git config.

Comment: It is already upgraded, but I am on a debian 7. I am new to debian. I assume it is very conservative ? kernel is 2.6.32. I am on a VPS. Anyway, `git remote add -t br2 origin https://www.github.com/project/project` is ok, and `git fetch origin` also in 33 sec.

Comment: @lalebarde great! I have updated my answer. Note that you can upgrade git: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25089714/6309